# Why are some of these Python object fields a tuple instead of the type from the source variable

Tags: python

Why do 2 of the class fields change their type to a tuple when the class is instantiated?

```
source_a = "ENVIRONMENT"
scopes = ["domain_read_only", "user_read_only"]
subject = "blah@blah.com"


class DataChunk:
    def __init__(self, source, impersonate, permissions):
        self.subject = impersonate,
        self.scopes = permissions,
        self.source = source


my_data_chunk = DataChunk(source=source_a, impersonate=subject, permissions=scopes)

print(f"my_data_chuck.subject: {type(my_data_chunk.subject)}")
print(f"my_data_chunk.scopes: {type(my_data_chunk.scopes)}")
print(f"my_data_chunk.source: {type(my_data_chunk.source)}")
print(f"subject: {my_data_chunk.subject}")
print(f"scopes: {my_data_chunk.scopes}")
print(f"source: {my_data_chunk.source}")
```

produces:

```
my_data_chuck.subject: <class 'tuple'>
my_data_chunk.scopes: <class 'tuple'>
my_data_chunk.source: <class 'str'>
subject: ('blah@blah.com',)
scopes: (['domain_read_only', 'user_read_only'],)
source: ENVIRONMENT
```

Why would subject and scopes be a tuple?
Why not source?

I've tried Python 3.6 and 3.8 and on a couple different systems.

Comment: Because of the trailing comma. Python will interpret that as a shortcut for (subject,) and turn it into a tuple

Comment: @LukasThaler: Nitpick: It's not a "shortcut"; with the exception of the empty tuple, `()`, `tuple`s in Python are primarily defined by the comma, not the parentheses; the parentheses are only there for precedence and disambiguation.

Comment: Learnt something new today :-) +1 from me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the comma in the class initialization, Use below class definition and see the output-

```
class DataChunk:
    def __init__(self, source, impersonate, permissions):
        self.subject = impersonate
        self.scopes = permissions
        self.source = source
```

Output

```
my_data_chuck.subject: <class 'str'>
my_data_chunk.scopes: <class 'list'>
my_data_chunk.source: <class 'str'>
subject: blah@blah.com
scopes: ['domain_read_only', 'user_read_only']
source: ENVIRONMENT
```

Comment: Guess I was going to fast and mentally mixing other notions together.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the comma you've added to the `impersonate` and the `permissions`.

The comma converts the object into a tuple.

Instead, do this:

```
class DataChunk:
    def __init__(self, source, impersonate, permissions):
        self.subject = impersonate
        self.scopes = permissions
        self.source = source
```